# get size of displayed web page without browser application bars with css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple web page that displays text from a text input, and I want to make the text input to take up the whole displayed web page (without the browser bar), the 100vh technique includes the browser bar and I do not want to guess the top bar size

Here is my code:

```js
function focus() { // to easily focus an element
 document.getElementById("title").focus();
}

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) { // make sure the user's focus is stuck to the text input 
 if (event.target !== document.getElementById("title")) {
  document.getElementById("title").focus();
 }
}, false);
window.onload = function () {document.getElementById("title").focus();};

function apply() { // applies title
 setTimeout(function () {
  var str = document.getElementById("title").value;
  if (!str.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
   document.title = "title-text";
  } else {
   document.title = str;
  }
 },1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title-text</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="title" onkeypress="apply()" autocomplete="off">
 </body>
</html>
```

(the JS binds the focus to the text box)

Comment: vh units doesn't count the browser bar, vh means "viewport height" and the viewport is the "actual page"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css classes to achieve this.

```
body{
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#title{
  height: 100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
```

Comment: the textbox becomes a little too big, and if I try and make it smaller, it glitches out. I think I will stick to the current size.